# IE8 & 9 jQuery MapHilihght Bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am using jQuery maphilight plugin: davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/ <-- (Sorry can only post 1 hyperlink).

I have copied the code exactly as the plugin to try and get it working. So far it works in FF, Chrome, IE7 but not IE8 or IE9?!

Here is my preview: http://www.globalpreviews2.co.uk/test/shops/

To test hover over the 'Male' icon.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem. I had this in my code:

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta3)/IE9.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Have swapped it for selectivizr: http://selectivizr.com/

All is now good.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with maphilight in IE6 and IE7. The `mouseover` and `mouseout` does not get triggered. There was a problem with the selector `area[coords]`. Change all `area[coords]` selectors just to area without `[coords]`.